# Quinquies and quinquiens

Tags: morphology, numbers, origin

Consider the word *quinquies/quinquiens* ("five times").
It has two alternative spellings.
Having the options *-ies* and *-iens* seems to be common for numerals of this kind.
What is the origin of these forms?
Why are there two alternatives?
I don't recall seeing any analogous spelling variants elsewhere in Latin; *faciens* and *facies* are very different things, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The etymologically expected form is *-iens*, but since the vowel preceding the *ns* was regularly lengthened, the pronunciation would be [ie:ns], in which the vowel was secondarily nasalized to [iẽ:ns].  This would naturally lead to sometimes omitting the [n] altogether, i.e. [iẽ:s]* (still probably phonemically /iens/), and possibly denasalized to [ie:s]**.

In words like *faciens*, the other declensional forms reinforced the pronunciation and spelling of the *n*, but in forms like *quinquiens/quinquies*, there was no such reinforcement, hence a more or less random pattern of the replacement from becoming the norm.

* This stage is like that of modern French, where syllable-final *n* or *m* is not pronounced itself, but serves as an indicator that the previous vowel is nasalized.

** This ultimately became the regular development in Spanish, as exemplified by L. *mensa* -> Sp. *mesa*.